# Selenium TakesScreenshot creates corrupted image

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, screenshot

I have an issue in my Selenum test project: my cucumber report sometimes does not display anything in the browser. The cause of this: sometimes the embedded screen shot (included for failed scenarios) is corrupt.

This is my code to capture the screenshot:

```
private void takeScreenshotIfScenarioFailed() {
    if (Context.scenario.isFailed()) {
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) Context.driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        Context.scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "screenshot");
    }
}
```

Any suggestion for to fix (occasional) corrupted screenshot?

I tried running the test headless, but the issue still occurs from time to time.

Comment: What does `corrupted` mean in the context of your situation?

Comment: In my cucumber.html file the images are in a tag like this <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgohIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="ORaS_8RRNPuyNQTWStAR">.
The part between the quotes is not correct to display the image. I can fix it via this site: https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image/png. This site gives an error for corrupted images and offers to fix it.

Comment: @Said does it necessary for you to take outputType as a bytes ?